# Text and numerical values in pivot tables in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a table in Excel that looks like this:

```
  Name      QuestionID      Answer
  A         1               Shoes
  B         1               Coats
  A         2               1983
  B         2               1978
```

I want to create a table that Looks like this:

```
  Name        1        2
  A          Shoes     1983
  B          Coats     1978
```

I've tried creating a pivot table, where "Name" is the row, "QuestionID" is a column, and "Answer" is the value. But values need to be aggregated, so I wind up with something numerical, instead of just the text or numbers in "Answers." I'm not clear on how to just display just the values, and not some processed version of the values.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: have you tried inputting `="1983"`?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  You can do it using DAX / by adding a  Measure to the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is why I never use Pivot Tables...they never seem to do what I need them to do.

Assuming that you can create a unique distinct list for the Header row & Name column manually, or auto-magically (see [unique distinct list](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/07/11/create-a-unique-distinct-sorted-list-containing-both-numbers-text-removing-blanks-in-excel/))

You could just use the following formula inside the table to do a lookup:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=$E2)*($B$2:$B$5=F$1)*ROW($C$2:$C$5))-ROW($C$1))
```

Where

> Source Table is in A1:C5
>
> Result Table - Name Column is E1:E3
>
> Headers (for Questions) are in cells F1:G1

---

If you break it up, it's just an `INDEX` table lookup

`=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,SOME_ROW)`

Where `SOME_ROW` is determined by

`SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=$E2)*($B$2:$B$5=F$1)*ROW($C$2:$C$5))`

Breaking the `SUMPRODUCT` down, we're just creating set of lists, of 1's & 0's (or True/False) for the search criteria.

The first column to match the `Name` is determined by `($A$2:$A$5=$E2)`

The second column to match the `Question` is determined by `($B$2:$B$5=F$1)`

Multiplying the two lists together, when `Name = A` & `Question =1` you get

`(A,B,A,B) * (1,1,2,2)` 
`(1,0,1,0) * (1,1,0,0) = (1,0,0,0)`

The third list (that we are going to multiply the above result with) from the `SUMPRODUCT`, is the actual Row; it's determined by `ROW($C$2:$C$5)`, so we get:

`(1,0,0,0) * (2,3,4,5) = (2,0,0,0)`

Now we `SUM` the `PRODUCTS` of the result:

`2 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 2`

So the actual result is in `Row 2`; Yes!

...but we have a problem; in the `INDEX` function, the the Array starts on Row 2, so if we specify the `2` for the `row number`, we'll actually get the value from row 3 because of the starting row offset.

This is where `-ROW($C$1)` comes in; to fix the row offset.  It should point to a cell in the header row.

It's much easier then it looks...